# HYPERLINK Formula with Word bookmarks

Tags: excel, hyperlink, ms-word, formula

I'm trying to link some cells to a specific bookmark within a Word document.

Doing this manually...

(Right click > Hyperlink > Address: *Word-Document-Adress* **#** *Bookmark-Name-1*)

...works ok. Clicking this cell opens the word document to the desired bookmark.

But what I want is to automatize this somehow.

I have a given Cell A1 containing *Word-Document-Adress* **#** *Bookmark-Name-1*

So I'm trying to use HYPERLINK formula:

```
=HYPERLINK(A1; "Go to Bookmark 1")
```

The hyperlink created contains just the *Word_Document_Adress* information so does not navigate to the desired bookmark.

Any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, odd enough I solve this while I'm posting it.

If I select the cell and remove the hyperlink... it lose the blue format but still navigates and this time to the correct section of the Word document.